# How do I get a Do function to create a list?

Tags: functions

I have a Do function which gives me a column of expressions. How can I get the Do function to give me these expressions in a list.

i.e The do function gives me this:
a
b
c
d

I would like it do give me this:
{a,b,c,d}

Comment: Please read [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/18396/193) first!

Comment: "The do function gives me this: a b c d" -- I do not even know how to interpret this. You need to be much more specific. Maybe you want to use `Append` somehow?

Comment: i'm going to guess you have a `Print[]` in the do?

Answer (score 1):

While belisarius is right that you can usually make the list you want directly with `Table`, I'm often in a situation where I need to build up a list with a `Do` loop.  Say I'm numerically propagating a wave function through a series of discrete time steps and need to collect the expectation values for several operators at each time point, this is how I do it.

```
(*Initialize the list outside the loop*)
list1 = {};
list2 = {};
Do[
 (*code here*)
 AppendTo[list1,value1];
 AppendTo[list2,value2];
 ,{n,ninit,nfin,nstep}];
```

Comment: have a look at `Reap/Sow`

Comment: `AppendTo` will lead to $O(n^2)$ complexity.  `Reap`/`Sow` will be much faster when collecting lots of results.

Comment: I can change it to use `Reap`/`Sow` but don't really see much improvement. When I run something like what I have written above, the part inside (*code here*) takes orders of magnitude longer to run than the `AppendTo` statements.  Also I don't see how to use `Reap` to generate multiple lists, aside from doing something like `biglist=Reap[Do[(*code here*)Sow[{value1,value2}];,{n,ninit,nfin,nstep}]][[2,1]];` and then after the loop is done, doing `{list1,list2}=Transpose[biglist];`.  So in my code this will only shave off at most 1% of the execution time, but I suppose every bit helps.

Answer (score 0):

So normally I would consider a "column" of expressions to be of the form:

```
col0={{"a"}, {"b"}, {"c"}, {"d"}}
```

Note that Mathematica uses [Row Major](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-major_order) order.

```
row0=First[Transpose[col0]]
```

would extract the first column into a row list.

As previously mentioned, appending to lists with AppendTo in a do loop can be expensive.  Avoid if possible. Consider using [Table](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Table.html) instead.

```
col1=Table[FromCharacterCode[{{iChr}}], {iChr, 97, 100, 1}]
row1=Table[FromCharacterCode@iChr, {iChr, 97, 100, 1}]
```

If the code in your Do loop is lengthy, you can address this by putting it into a module, and then calling that module from the Table command.  (i.e. Replace FromCharacterCode in the toy example with a function call to your module.)